# PHP Function return data to an array

Tags: php, arrays, function, post, multidimensional-array

I have few php functions that returns various data via same variable, and that variable should assign to a array. Now I want to execute function by checking `$_POST` and assign $data to `$response` multidimensional array... Is there any way to do that ???

```
$functionname = $_POST['functionname'];

function testOne(){
$data = array('test'=>'value1');
return $data;
}

function testTwo(){
$data = array('test'=>'value2');
return $data;
}

//Here I need to execte each functions and return $data

$response = array('result' => array('response'=>'success'),'clients' => $data);

print_r($response);
```

Comment: Do you mean `$data = $functioname()`? If so, that is a very insecure way of writing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions are only run when they're called. You haven't called either of your functions.

From the looks of your code, I assume that `$functionname` will take a value of either `testOne` or `testTwo`, which then tells the code what function to run. What you want to do, then, is call the function using the variable function name and capture the returned value into a variable:

```
$functionname = $_POST['functionname'];
//function definitions
$response = array('result' => array('response'=>'success'), 'clients' => $functionname());
```

See [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) for, well... the docs.

Comment: You need to validate and sanitize the input. Now anybody can call any PHP or user function. Granted, they cannot supply parameters, but it's still an extremely bad way of doing this.

Comment: @stackminu what happens when someone hacks your code ... that function could be anything ....

Comment: @stackminu What they said. I just gave you a basic "here's how to do what you want"; you need to secure it to make sure it's used the way you want it to be used.

Answer (score 1):

you can call the function inside of an array directly.

```
$response = array('result' => array('response'=>'success'),'clients' => testTwo());
```

now in `$response['clients']` the value will contain `array('test'=>'value2');`

or if you want to call a function through user input, for example. if

```
if $_POST['funtionname'] = 'testOne'; then execute testOne();
if $_POST['funtionname'] = 'testTwo'; then execute testTwo();
```

then you can make use of `call_user_func()` here. like this.

```
$_POST['funtionname'] = 'testOne';
call_user_func($_POST['functionname']);
//this will execute testOne(); and depending upon the value it consist, it will execute the corresponding function.
```

if that is what you mean. correct me if i understood it wrong.

Comment: But I want to call that function using `$functionname = $_POST['functionname'];` Because user(client) requests what function he wants to execute. [This is a API] :)

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. @Palladium told me a easy way to do this. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to call the function from within the `$functionname` variable .. if so this is how you do it :

```
$data = call_user_func($functionname);
$response = array('result' => array('response'=>'success'),'clients' => $data);
```

in this case the value of `$functionname` should either be `testOne` or `testTwo`

[Docs for `call_user_func` here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)